# How to prevent layout shift when TextInputLayout error is shown

Tags: android-layout, textinputlayout

I have a login screen with email and password fields using TextInputEditTexts within TextInputLayouts inside a ConstraintLayout.

When an error message is set to a TextInputLayout it shiftes down all controls below it.

[image]

I know that this behavior is normal but how can I prevent the shift, i.e. make the distance between the TextInputEditText and the following control fixed regardless of the error status.

Answer (score 1):

A workarround is to put a space into the helperText attribute `app:helperText=" "`